# Does Orion-LD support temporal query language from the NGSI-LD specification?

Tags: fiware-orion

In the "[ETSI GS CIM 009 V1.2.1 (2019-10). Context Information Management (CIM); NGSI-LD API](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gs/CIM/001_099/009/01.02.01_60/gs_cim009v010201p.pdf)" standard there is a chapter "4.11 NGSI-LD Temporal Query language".

> *The NGSI-LD Temporal Query language shall be supported by implementations. It is intended to define predicates
> which allow testing whether Temporal Properties of NGSI-LD Entities, Properties and Relationships, are within certain
> temporal constraints. In particular it can be used to request historic Property values and Relationships that were valid
> within the specified timeframe.
> The following grammar defines the syntax that shall be supported:
> timerel = beforeRel / afterRel / betweenRel
> beforeRel = "before"
> afterRel = "after"
> betweenRel = "between"
> The points in time for comparison are defined as follows:
> • A time element, which shall represent the comparison point for the before and after relation and the starting
> point for the between relation. It shall be represented as DateTime (mandated by clause 4.6.3).
> • An endtime element, which is only used for the between relation and shall represent the end point for
> comparison. It shall be represented as DateTime (mandated by clause 4.6.3).*

And in the "C.5.5 Temporal Query" there is query example

```
GET /ngsild/v1/*temporal*/entities/?type=Vehicle&q=brandName!=Mercedes&attrs=speed,brandName**&timerel=between
&time=2018-08-01:12:00:00Z&endTime=2018-08-01:13:00:00Z**
```

I'm trying to run similar GET request(Orion-LD (with Mintaka)) against certain data and get "400" back with: "time is unknown" (or "endTime is unknown" if I remove "time" condition from the string).

If I remove the  part of the request that has timerel, time and endDate, then this GET request returns data fine. Therefore I was wondering if the part of the specification described in"4.11 NGSI-LD Temporal Query language".  has been implemented in Orion_LD?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Orion-LD does support the Temporal Interfaces of NGSI-LD, it just requires the component "Mintaka" for that:  https://github.com/FIWARE/mintaka
Orion-LD needs to store the data in TimescaleDB, where it than can be retrieved via Mintaka. To enable the storage on timescale, see https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/blob/develop/doc/manuals-ld/troe.md

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The text available via the link you've sent says: "Starting with the Orion-LD release Beta 2, Orion-LD implements Temporal Representation of Entities (TRoE), in an experimental state. The feature is minimally tested and not production-ready, but more or less working and the development team would be more than happy to have it tested, and any bugs reported."

Do you know where the list of implemented TRoE features can be found?

Thank you